# trying to calculate the date difference only for particular group value =abc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RateTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #RateTable

    CREATE TABLE #RateTable(
    [FILE_ID] [int],
    [Value] varchar(3) NULL,
    [RecordDate] [DateTime] NULL
    )
GO

INSERT INTO #RateTable VALUES (1700,'xyz','2012-01-01');

INSERT INTO #RateTable VALUES (1700,'xyz','2012-01-02');

INSERT INTO #RateTable VALUES (1700,'abc','2012-01-02');

INSERT INTO #RateTable VALUES (1700,'abc','2012-01-03');

INSERT INTO #RateTable VALUES (1700,'xyz','2012-01-04');

INSERT INTO #RateTable VALUES (1700,'xyz','2012-01-05');

INSERT INTO #RateTable VALUES (1700,'xyz','2012-01-06');

INSERT INTO #RateTable VALUES (1700,'abc','2012-01-10');

INSERT INTO #RateTable VALUES (1700,'abc','2012-01-13');

INSERT INTO #RateTable VALUES (1700,'abc','2012-01-20');

INSERT INTO #RateTable VALUES (2587,'abc','2012-03-10');

INSERT INTO #RateTable VALUES (2587,'abc','2012-03-15');

INSERT INTO #RateTable VALUES (2587,'abc','2012-03-20');

INSERT INTO #RateTable VALUES (2587,'abc','2012-03-21');

GO
--select * from #RateTable
```

The desired output for Value = 'abc' is:

```
FILE_ID      Value    FIRSTDATE     LASTDATE

1700         abc     01/02/2012    01/03/2012

1700         abc     01/10/2012    01/20/2012

2587         abc     03/10/2012    03/21/2012
```

Please let me know if it is possible to get output without using cursors. CTEs are available option for me.

Answer (score 1):

This query just gives you a general idea, for I don't fully understand what you want.

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT * 
                 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FILE_ID, Value ORDER BY RecordDate) AS Rownum
              FROM #RateTable
)
SELECT t1.FILE_ID
    , t1.Value
    , t1.RecordDate AS FirstDate
    , ISNULL(t2.RecordDate, t1.RecordDate) AS LastDate
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2 
    ON t1.FILE_ID = t2.FILE_ID 
    AND t1.Value = t2.Value 
    AND t1.Rownum = t2.Rownum - 1;
```

To answer you comment, how you define 1700 has 2 instances only?

```
FILE_ID     Value   RecordDate

1700        abc     2012-01-02 00:00:00.000
1700        abc     2012-01-03 00:00:00.000
1700        abc     2012-01-10 00:00:00.000
1700        abc     2012-01-13 00:00:00.000
1700        abc     2012-01-20 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: File 1700 has two instances of abc, I need individual time period for each abc like I had stated in the output above.

Comment: This query is just to give you some idea like I said. There is no way to tell 1700 has 2 instances only based on your information.

Answer (score 1):

OK: As I noted in my comment, what it appears you want is:

> For any `FILE_ID`, assuming our data is ordered on `RecordDate`, consider all consecutive rows with the same `value` as a group.
>
> Given a specific target `value`, return the first last last `RecordDate` for each group with that `value`, for all `FILE_ID`s.

Note that a single row with the value '*X*' (that is, where the row with the next lowest `RecordDate` has a different `value` (or this is the first row), and the row with the next highest `RecordDate` has a different `value` (or this is the last row)), that single row should be treated as a group on its own, and its `RecordDate` would be both `FirstDate` and `LastDate`.

I got the following code to work, using the test data provided, with the addition of an entry to test out the "single row group" option:

```
INSERT INTO #RateTable VALUES (3543,'abc','2012-03-15');
```

Here's my code:

```
DECLARE @target_value varchar(100);
SET @target_value = 'abc';

-- We need to identify consecutive rows;
--   establishing a row order within each FILE_ID will let us do that.
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#OrderedRateTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #OrderedRateTable
;

CREATE TABLE #OrderedRateTable(
[FILE_ID] [int],
[row_num] [int],
[Value] varchar(3) NULL,
[RecordDate] [DateTime] NULL
);

-- Let's only worry about FILE_IDs that have the target value we're looking for
WITH myFILE_IDs as
     (SELECT FILE_ID
        FROM #RateTable
       WHERE value = @target_value
       GROUP BY FILE_ID
     )
INSERT INTO #OrderedRateTable
SELECT t.FILE_ID
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.FILE_ID ORDER BY t.RecordDate) as row_num
      ,t.value
      ,t.RecordDate
  FROM #RateTable t
         INNER JOIN myFILE_IDs f ON (t.FILE_ID = f.FILE_ID)
;


-- Any record:
--  - that has our target value
--  - where either
--    - it's the first record for the FILE_ID, or
--    - the previous record has a different value
-- starts a group.

-- Similarly, any record:
--  - that has our target value
--  - where either
--    - the next record has a different value, or
--    - it's the last record for the FILE_ID
-- ends a group.

-- Match the starts in order by RecordDate to the ends, also in order
--   by RecordDate, and we'll have our group starts and ends together.

WITH Floors AS
     (SELECT FILE_ID
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FILE_ID ORDER BY RecordDate) as match_num
            ,value
            ,RecordDate
        FROM #OrderedRateTable fl
       WHERE value = @target_value
          -- and the previous row for this FILE_ID has a different value (or doesn't exist)
         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                           FROM #OrderedRateTable
                          WHERE FILE_ID = fl.FILE_ID
                            AND value = fl.value
                            AND row_num = fl.row_num - 1
                        )
     )
    ,Ceilings AS
     (SELECT FILE_ID
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FILE_ID ORDER BY RecordDate) as match_num
            ,value
            ,RecordDate
        FROM #OrderedRateTable cl
       WHERE value = @target_value
          -- and the next row for this FILE_ID has a different value (or doesn't exist)
         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                           FROM #OrderedRateTable
                          WHERE FILE_ID = cl.FILE_ID
                            AND value = cl.value
                            AND row_num = cl.row_num + 1
                        )
     )
SELECT fl.FILE_ID
      ,fl.value
      ,CONVERT(varchar(10), fl.RecordDate, 101) AS FirstDate
      ,CONVERT(varchar(10), cl.RecordDate, 101) AS LastDate
  FROM Floors fl
         INNER JOIN Ceilings cl ON (    fl.FILE_ID = cl.FILE_ID
                                    AND fl.match_num = cl.match_num
                                   )
 ORDER BY FILE_ID, value, FirstDate, LastDate
;
```

As noted in the code comments, we:

1. Create an ordered copy of `#RateTable`, with sequential row number assigned from 1 up for each `FILE_ID`, with the data sorted by `RecordDate`. This gives us an easy way to identify our groups of rows with the same `value`s. (There are alternate methods).
2. Using the data, identify all the rows that start a group with our target `value`, and all the rows that end a group with our target `value`.
3. For each `FILE_ID`, match the first start (sorted by `RecordDate`) with the first end, the second start with the second end, etc.
4. Return `FILE_ID`, the target `value`, the start date and the matched end date.

Results:

```
FILE_ID     value FirstDate  LastDate
----------- ----- ---------- ----------
1700        abc   01/02/2012 01/03/2012
1700        abc   01/10/2012 01/20/2012
2587        abc   03/10/2012 03/21/2012
3543        abc   03/15/2012 03/15/2012
```

NOTE: For very large files, you may not want to materialize the `#OrderedRateTable` table. You can try to simply set that up as another CTE. To do so:

- Remove the command to `DROP` and `CREATE` `#OrderedRateTable`;
- Replace these lines:

  ```
  INSERT INTO #OrderedRateTable
  SELECT t.FILE_ID
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.FILE_ID ORDER BY t.RecordDate) as row_num
        ,t.value
        ,t.RecordDate
    FROM #RateTable t
           INNER JOIN myFILE_IDs f ON (t.FILE_ID = f.FILE_ID)
  ;
  ```

  with these:

  ```
      ,OrderedRateTable As
       (SELECT t.FILE_ID
              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.FILE_ID ORDER BY t.RecordDate) as row_num
              ,t.value
              ,t.RecordDate
          FROM #RateTable t
                 INNER JOIN myFILE_IDs f ON (t.FILE_ID = f.FILE_ID)
       )
  ```
- change:

  ```
  WITH Floors AS
  ```

  to:

  ```
      ,Floors AS
  ```
- change `#OrderedRateTable` to `OrderedRateTable` for all lines below the changed ones.

I decided to materialize that part of the query because SQL Server appears to run the query behind the CTE each time the CTE is used; this means that, with `OrderedRateTable` as a CTE, the query to sort and number all the rows is run 4 times. While we don't have enough data to be sure, I strongly suspect that running the query once into a temp table and using the results from there may perform better than running it 4 times.